# How to generate ios folder after doing expo eject?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I run expo eject i got my android folder the app works perfectly on android but it didn't generate the ios folder and i can't now test my app on IOS

Comment: Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

it's solved there, you must setup a new project with the same project name and move ios folder in your first project directorie
https://lifesaver.codes/answer/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project-808